# How to use the Directory.GetFiles() method to choose between today's date and another date?

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to find files using XML Reader which meet some conditions including if the File Age is Younger than a certain number. I am getting an error for CreationTime but I do not understand how to get through it. d1 is the current date and d2 is the date range for the youngest file

Error   CS1061  'string' does not contain a definition for 'CreationTime' and no accessible extension method 'CreationTime' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
 public int FileAgeYounger 
            {
                get
                {
                    return FileAgeYounger;
                }
                set
                {
                    DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
                    d2 = d1.AddDays(FileAgeYounger);


                    if (subfolders == true & FileExtension != null & Fileprefix != null & FileUseRelativeAgeYounger == true) 
                    {
                        FolderLocation2 = Directory.GetFiles(FolderLocation, Fileprefix + FileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(f => f.CreationTime >= d2 && f.CreationTime <= d1));
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You want a `FileInfo` instance. `GetFiles` returns just file paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directory.GetFiles` returns only the name of the file.
You can use `DirectoryInfo` instead.

```
FileInfo[] fileInfos = new DirectoryInfo(FolderLocation).GetFiles();
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = fileInfos.Where((f) => f.Extension.Equals(FileExtension) 
            && f.Name.StartsWith(Fileprefix) 
            && f.CreationTime >= d2 
            && f.CreationTime <= d1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Directory.GetFiles` returns collection of string and on this strings collection (please refer MSDN documentaiton [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_)) you are trying to use file (System.IO.File) methods like `CreationTime` and hence the error.

If you want sort on CreationTime, please use [DirectoryInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo?view=netframework-4.8).

```
DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FolderLocation);
FileInfo[] files = info.GetFiles().OrderBy(p => p.CreationTime).ToArray();
```